# How can "bin, lib, lib64 and sbin" folders be magically removed from Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

The other day I tried to reboot my Ubuntu 20 server and it kept failing on boot with a "Kernel Panic". After investigating using the "rescue mode" provided by our service provider, we found that on the root directory we did not have any of the folders:

- bin
- lib
- lib64
- sbin

We fixed it creating symlinks to the /usr/xxx equivalents and it started smoothly

At this point, I do not know how it could happen.

1. Is there any known vulneravility or exploit with these symptoms?
2. What should I check to find out more about the root cause?

**-- EDIT --**

I have checked the history as root as suggested in the answer, but I cannot see anything related with a "rm -rf *" (or similar) that involved the folder that "magically dissapeared". The output I got:

**history | grep rm**

```
  887  rm 09
  888  rm _new*
  891  rm _new*
  893  rm _new*
  916  rm _new_*
  918  rm _new_*
  922  rm _new_*
  927  rm _*
  934  rm _*
  936  rm _*
  974  rm woo*
  975  rm -r woocommerce_uploads/
  980  rm -r test/
 1024  rm -r directory-files-converter_MODIFIED/
 1165  history | grep rm
```

**history | grep bin**

```
  502  joe /usr/local/bin/copias
  516  joe /usr/local/bin/copias
  518  joe /usr/local/bin/copias
  520  joe /usr/local/bin/copias
  575  cd /usr/local/bin/
  609  cd /usr/local/bin/dreport
  610  cd /usr/local/bin/dcheck/
  760  cat /usr/local/bin/copias
  764  /usr/local/bin/dreport
 1166  history | grep bin
```

Any other idea of where to look?

Answer (score 2):

Someone or something executed `rm /*` with root privileges. Check `history` (as root).

Alternatively, I've seen enough poorly written scripts with code of this form in them:

```
rm $someVar/*
```

The expectation is that `$someVar` is never empty and doesn't contain characters of `$IFS` or wildcards and doesn't start with `-`. What can trigger your scenario, however, is that `$someVar` is empty, where the variable is expanded and the command becomes this:

```
rm /*
```

Or `$someVar` ends in a character that happens to be present in `$IFS` (space, tab, newline by default), such as `someVar='dir '` in which case the command becomes:

```
rm dir /*
```

The code could be better written `rm -- "$someVar"/*` which would address the latter issue, but that still wouldn't cope with the situation that `$someVar` was empty. Two alternatives might be:

```
[ -n "$someVar" ] && rm -f -- "$someVar"/*    # Execute only if set

rm -f -- "${someVar:?is undefined}"/*         # Abort with error if unset or empty
```

Setting the `nounset` option (`set -o nounset` or `set -u`) which causes shell processes to abort when an unset variable is dereferenced, also helps detect typos in variable names which can lead to this kind of issue.

Comment: I have edited the question adding the output for history command. Any other idea?

Comment: @JaviM, yes - the other part of my answer

Comment: I we do not have any script like that on our system... I checked it as well. Is there any known exploit or vulnerability that can do something like this?

Comment: Not that I know of. There are better ways to cripple a system, which is why I think it's accidental